# Unknown column 'password' in 'field list' mysql

Tags: mysql

1)I did log in with mysql -u root -p

2)use mysql

3)describe user -->

[image]

And it shows that I have a field "Password"

I updated the authentication_string before with : ***UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string= '1234' WHERE User = 'root';***

Also used : ***update user set authentication_string=password('1234') where user='root';***

This is the error : **Error: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'**

It's very weird :D .Should I change the password again ?

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Please if its text post the text. Not Pictures of text

Comment: I don't understand the issue. I don't see you referencing the `password` column anywhere. In your query you only use the `password` function.

Comment: @El_Vanja Woops, time for another cup of tea

Comment: Maybe `user` !== `User`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope, [not case sensitive](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b21139/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password says:

> **Note** This function is deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and is removed in MySQL 8.0.

To change a user's password, do not manipulate the `mysql.user` table directly.

To change a password, use [ALTER USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';
```

See documentation for more examples and explanation.

Comment: Not good. 'Password' field was used to determine if any password is set. initially it was "invalid" now it's difficult to debug.

Comment: @Sebastian Regarding the password field in the mysql system schema, you may now check `user.authentication_string`. If that field is blank, then no password is set for that user.